# How to getan object passed by an AJAX into controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-7

i want to pass update data using ajax . i m tried to send all data from ajax but in controller when i do **dd($request)** getting bellow error

`<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpper`

I am not getting what is exact error show in when dd . If i do print_r($request) then also not getting data

Below is my html code of edit form

```
<form id="productForm" name="productForm" class="form-horizontal">
              <!-- @csrf -->
                  <!-- {{ csrf_field() }} -->
                  <div class="form-label-group">
                  <label for="inputName">First Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="inputName" name="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" autofocus>
                  
                  @if ($errors->has('fname'))
                  <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('fname') }}</span>
                  @endif       
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-label-group">
                  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" autofocus>
                  
                  @if ($errors->has('lname'))
                  <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('lname') }}</span>
                  @endif       
                  </div> 
                  <div class="form-label-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email address" >
                  
                  @if ($errors->has('email'))
                  <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                  @endif    
                  </div> 

                  <div class="form-label-group">
                  <label for="inputusername">User Name</label>
                  <input type="text" id="inputusername" name="username" class="form-control"   placeholder="User name" autofocus>
                  
                  @if ($errors->has('username'))
                  <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
                  @endif       
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-label-group">
                  <label for="inputusername">User Role</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state-dropdown">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                   </select> 
                  @if ($errors->has('username'))
                  <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
                  @endif       
                  </div>

                  
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary edit_form" id="btn-save">Save changes
                 </button>
                  <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-cancel" value="create">Cancel
                 </button> -->
               </div>

                </form>
```

below is ajax file from where call route and send data

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit_form', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $('#productForm').serialize();
    //  alert(data);
    //  console.log(data);
                    $.ajax({

                              url:"{{url('store')}}",
                              type: "POST",
                              data: {
                                formdata : formdata,
                              _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' 
                              },
                              dataType : 'json',
                              success: function (data) {
                                console.log("hii");
                              },
                              error: function (data) {

                              }
                    })
    
    });
```

Below is my route

```
Route::get('/user-list/{id}/edit', 'UserController@editUser');
Route::post('store', 'UserController@userStore');
```

Nd below is my controller function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Use App\User;
Use App\ROle;
use DataTables,DB;
use Validator,Redirect,Response;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Mail\VarificationEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function editUser($id)
    {
        $cid = array('id' => $id);

        $data  = User::where($cid)->first();

        $user_id = $data->id;
       
        $data['user']  = User::where('id',$user_id)->first();

        $data['roles'] = Role::all();
        return Response::json($data);
    }

     public function userStore(Request $request)
        {
            echo "hii";
            echo "<pre>";
            dd($request->get('first_name'));   
                // die;
        }
}
```

I am not getting what exact doing wrong in this . its really confusing. If anyone have have idea then let me know.

in formdata getting below data. more details please find details

[image]

and below is error attachment

[image]

Anyone have idea then please let me know.

Comment: that isn't an "error" that is the `dd` call, that is the HTML it returns to be able to render variable you are dumping

Comment: @lagbox   Then how I get the value of input into the controller?